# Change port of installed device

Tags: windows-7

I have a USB bluetooth connector but it just seems to work in one specific USB port. When I try it in other ports it is not recognised.  Can the port for this bluetooth connector be changed to point at a different USB port?

Comment: We need more information with regards to the port and the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to install it on multiple compatible USB ports, though you will need admin rights to do so. I’d suggest having a look in Device Manager (devmgmt.msc) under Universal Serial Bus Connectors first to see if it’s giving any errors. Attempt to re-install the driver automatically if need be.